# Error on sending input data to model attribute on yii1

Tags: php, model, yii1.x

> Illegal offset type in isset or empty
>   (/Applications/AMPPS/www/framework/validators/CValidator.php:235)

I am getting above error from model file while setting input data to model attribute on yii.

Below is my code for controller:

```
$model = new Customer();        
$model->attributes = $_POST;
```

Model rules

```
 public function rules() {
    return array(
      array('cust_id, name, price', 'required', 'on' => array('update')),

    );
}
```

Comment: how are you submitting the data, is it an activeform? add your complete action that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the model name during this assignment `$model->attributes = $_POST;`

For example `$model->attributes = $_POST['Customer']`;

In `$_POST` there are other arguments to for example  `$_POST['SUBMITBUTTONNAME']`,
but your `Customer` model does not have such attribute so you get an error.

Or you should write your code like this

`$model->username = $_POST['username'];
$model->email = $_POST['email'];`